# Fallout new vegas not showing up mods

Tags: technical-issues, mods, fallout-new-vegas, nexus-mod-manager

So I got myself a copy of fallout new vegas to play. Everything goes fine except mods. I use the Nexus Mod Manager and have followed every single step on how to download and install mods. 
So my problem is that everything goes fine, the NMM installs the mod but at the moment of running the game it is still vanilla. I have already checked if the .esp mod files are selected, they are installed, everything seems to be functioning correctly. Yet they won't appear in game.

¿How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried installing the mods manually by placing them in the right folder manually? Nexus Mod Manager recently redesigned their system to make use of mod profiles, and I've found that sometimes, mod profiles fail to work properly.

Comment: Well the mod files are in the correct folder, even manual install won't make them appear.

Comment: What folder is New Vegas installed into? What version of Windows do you have? Is UAC turned on? We need more details to be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

While the Nexus Mod Manager makes things pretty simple to install mods, the notoriously unreliable game means there's a variety of reasons your mods may not be loading.

- Make sure you're starting the game from the correct executable. Foundational mods like New Vegas Scrip Extender (NVSE) may modify the launcher in addition to the game itself. In not done properly you may be clicking on the unedited launcher instead of the modded version of the game.
- Make sure your mods are enabled within Vortex. Installing the mod with a manager may install it in the load order, but leave it disabled. Check the mods tab of your Mod Manager to make sure that all your relevant mods are turned on.
- Not all mods provide a visual change. The famous ENB shader mod provides a toolkit that lets other modders drastically change the visuals of the game - but the default installation doesn't have those changes itself.
- Of course, the mods may be installed improperly. It may be necessary to change the .ini files to make the mod operable on your computer. This will usually need to be solved on a case-by-case basis.

Ultimately, it is necessary to post your mod list to provide more accurate help than just this. Similarly, you may want to go to Reddit.com/r/FalloutMods for more specialized help with specific mods.

Answer (score -2):

You don't use Nexus Mod Manager, it's garbage. Nexus Mod Manager causes a lot of problems and I have wasted countless hours before I finally realized I needed to switch to [Mod Organizer](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/42572/). Use Mod Organizer or [Fallout Mod Manager](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/36901/) instead.

Basically, for any game that uses mods, you want to use something besides Nexus Mod Manager, usually Mod Organizer or Mod Organizer 2. For using Fallout New Vegas with mods, make sure you are launching through New Vegas Script Extender, not the Steam library, and have all the proper patches like Yukichigai Unofficial Patch or "FOOK", anti-crash mods like New Vegas Anti-Crash, and User Interface Organizer, The Mod Configuration Menu, The Weapon Mod Menu, and a HUD mod like One Hud - oHUD first, before you install any other mods.

Comment: You may want to explain the acronyms you are using